# Why am I still committed to a site already in private beta?

Tags: support, area-51, commitment-phase, private-beta

The [*Ebooks* proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/ebooks) is already in private beta testing, but [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange_Network#area51) still says I am committed to it:

[image]

Also, when I try to commit to another proposal, I get a pop-up telling me that I am already committed to three proposals.

[image]

Why am I still committed to the proposal even when it is already in beta testing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't *fulfilled* your commitment, which is something you do by participating in the beta. The whole point of committing is to get people who are agreeing to try and get the site off the ground, so you have to demonstrate that you're one of those people before you're allowed to commit to further proposals*.

As mentioned in the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq):

> If you are very active, you may be able to re-use your commitment as soon as the second day of public beta. If you aren't active on the site, you won't be able to re-use the commitment until the end of the public beta, or until six months after the beta began.

<sub>*Once you've used up your 3 available commitments, anyway. You can also just wait the beta period out, but participating would be better for obvious reasons.</sub>

Comment: I though When I commited to pets, I was able to use my commitment the day it entered beta. It seems that's just in my head?

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I wouldn't have expected it to immediately let you use another commitment without something else at play.